# Finding a point along a line a certain distance away from another point!

Tags: geometry

Let's say you have two points, $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$.

The gradient of the line between them is:

$$m = (y_1 - y_0)/(x_1 - x_0)$$

And therefore the equation of the line between them is:

$$y = m (x - x_0) + y_0$$

Now, since I want another point along this line, but a distance $d$ away from $(x_0, y_0)$, I will get an equation of a circle with radius $d$ with a center $(x_0, y_0)$ then find the point of intersection between the circle equation and the line equation.

Circle Equation w/ radius $d$:

$$(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = d^2$$

Now, if I replace $y$ in the circle equation with $m(x - x_0) + y_0$ I get:

$$(x - x_0)^2 + m^2(x - x_0)^2 = d^2$$

I factor is out and simplify it and I get:

$$x = x_0 \pm d/ \sqrt{1 + m^2}$$

However, upon testing this equation out it seems that it does not work! Is there an obvious error that I have made in my theoretical side or have I just been fluffing up my calculations?

Comment: Looks about right to me. In particular, it gives the right result for reasonable values of $m = 0$, $m = 1$, $m = \infty$. Maybe there is a bug in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Rahul, i've been trying to programme this and you are right! it was an error in my implementation. Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: See formula 14 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html).

Comment: @enzotib: It is considered impolite in this site to remove or add "thank you" comments.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: sorry, I didn't know, in other SE sites it is considered superfluous to have such comments. I will take it into account for the future.

Comment: @Asaf: I didn't know that either. Is there a meta thread about this that I missed?

Comment: @Rahul: You can see that more than a handful of people expressed this opinion in various comments over meta threads. I cannot give you any recent event which is not a comment I wrote. However it feels that at least those participating the meta discussions tend to agree with that. If your Google search-fu is good you can probably find such comments on your own.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Another way, using vectors:

Let $\mathbf v = (x_1,y_1)-(x_0,y_0)$. Normalize this to $\mathbf u = \frac{\mathbf v}{||\mathbf v||}$.

The point along your line at a distance $d$ from $(x_0,y_0)$ is then $(x_0,y_0)+d\mathbf u$, if you want it in the direction of $(x_1,y_1)$, or $(x_0,y_0)-d\mathbf u$, if you want it in the opposite direction. One advantage of doing the calculation this way is that you won't run into a problem with division by zero in the case that $x_0 = x_1$.

Comment: Thanks Theophile, absolutely ace method. I didn't even think about vectors!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on this solution or point me to a link so that I can understand it a little more? A program written would be awesome as well.

Comment: @Dewey Which part are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: How would you do Normalize this to u=v/||v||?

Comment: @Dewey The length of a vector $\mathbf v = (v_1,v_2)$ is defined as $||\mathbf v|| = \sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2}$. The vector $\mathbf v \over ||\mathbf v||$, that is, $\Big(\dfrac{v_1}{\sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2}}, \dfrac{v_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2}}\Big)$, points in the same direction as $\mathbf v$ and has unit length. For example, if $\mathbf v = (3,4)$, then $\mathbf u = ({3 \over 5}, {4 \over 5})$.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this answer because I can't read the math notations and don't know what to Google. ("Vector notation" gives me something different). Anyway, I'm trying to solve individually for x and y given a distance. So I'd get x = x0 + du and y = y0 + du. But I can't figure out what du would be for the x component and the y component... can someone help?

Comment: @jpwrunyan Which notation are you having difficulty with?

Comment: lol, I wish I knew how to write them. I also think I figured out the answer I was looking for, but I wish I could read the ||v|| or understand how to write it in high school math format. The v2/1 (where the 2 is over the 1) and v2/2 also throw me off. Is that referring to column/row where the x and y's are in a matrix? I can *barely* read matrix notation since I use it sometimes in programming. Thanks for asking by the way. I feel my question here probably needs to be asked elsewhere since it's pretty broadly "how do I read math"?

Comment: @jpwrunyan Ah, I see! Okay, first, $||\bf v||$ refers to the length of the vector $\bf v$, which you can calculate using Pythagoras's theorem. In other words, if ${\bf v}=(x,y)$, then its length is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Next, about $v_1^2$ and $v_2^2$: these are easier than you think! They're just a compact way of writing $(v_1)^2$ and $(v_2)^2$, so in fact they aren't related to matrix notation (although that was a good guess). So if ${\bf v}=(x,y)$, then $||{\bf v}||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$; this is exactly the same as my previous comment but with differently named variables. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes! The first part about ||v|| makes sense. In v = (x, y), the x and y are x2 - x1 and y2 - y1. And now that you pointed it out, the power notation is obvious. I don't know what was wrong with me.

Comment: [How does this vector addition work in geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426807/72041)

Answer (score 64):

Let me explain the answer in a simple way.

Start point - $(x_0, y_0)$

End point - $(x_1, y_1)$

We need to find a point $(x_t, y_t)$ at a distance $d_t$ from start point towards end point.

[image: Point on a line at a distance]

The distance between Start and End point is given by $d = \sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2}$

Let the ratio of distances, $t=d_t/d$

Then the point $(x_t, y_t) =(((1-t)x_0+tx_1), ((1-t)y_0+ty_1))$

When $0<t<1$, the point is on the line.

When $t<0$, the point is outside the line near to $(x_0,y_0)$.

When $t>1$, the point is outside the line near to $(x_1,y_1)$.

Comment: Shouldn't `t = d / dt`?

Comment: @skibulk nope it's `t = dt / t` when I applied this to my code I followed your comment. But something was bugging out, turns out `t = dt / t` is correct.

Comment: @Marlon Thank you for confirming it.

Comment: Oh yes, you're correct. For some reason it I was thinking dt was "distance total" of the segment, which is be the divisor. Bit I guess it's supposed to be "distance time". Anyway, it's correct according to the illustration.

Comment: Multiplying x1 and y1 by t is clear but  what is the logic behind multiplying x0 and y0 by (1-t) in  (xt,yt)=(((1−t)x0+tx1),((1−t)y0+ty1)) ? Playing with the formula made it clear it was necessary but I wasn't able to intuit the logic behind it.

Comment: If you only want to extend the line by a percentage, you don't need to calculate the distance, where `p` is a decimal percentage: `dt = d * p`, `t = (d * p) / d`, thus `t = p`

Comment: what if the second point is origin (i.e 0,0) ?  I'm trying to use this for a pie chart centered at 0,0 and to move the slices, i get a line between start and end point of arc, from that line's center to the origin of the pie, a line is drawn and 20% of that line is what my pie should move to.

Comment: @CosmoArun I presume you mean a [Nightingale's Rose chart](https://www.google.com/search?q=Nightingale%27s+Rose+chart&tbm=isch). In normal pie chart you might not need to move along a line at any angle. Consider your points in reverse order, for 20% from origin, t = 0.2 and you will get the points (0.2*x1, 0.2*y1) where (x1, y1) is your end point.

Comment: @SenJacob  , I did it and it's working. Look at Pontios answer here (seems to me an extension of your answer). well descriptive, besides I have a largeArc Flag set for larger arcs more than 180 deg. So, svg takes care of the rest. (PS: I did it in SVG and it works great! thanks though!)  Anyway, you deserve a upvote, I just upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 21):

You can very easily find it with trigonometry!!

Let's say **Xa** and **Xb** are the two points of your line, and **D** is the distance between them. And you are looking to find **Xc** which is **D2** away from **Xa**  (as the diagram bellow):

[image]

You can easily find **D**:

[image: euclidean distance between Xa and Xb]

The formulas that you can find **Xa**, **Xb**, **Xc**, **D** and **D2** are:

[image]

But **SIN**a-b and **SIN**a-c share the same the same corner, so they are equal:

[image]

Since you know the distance (**D2**) between **Xa** and **Xc** that you are looking for, you can easily solve the following:

[image]

In conclusion by solving the formula for **D** and the last one you are done.
(You need one for the **Y** as well, just replace in the last one, **X** with **Y** )

Hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks this was really helpful

Comment: sweet solution!

Comment: what tool did you use to draw the sketch?

Comment: @ddzzbbwwmm I think it was inkscape. A good online alternative is: https://www.draw.io/

Comment: @Pontios Geogebra would be an interesting online alternative. https://www.geogebra.org/classic?lang=en

Answer (score 3):

The easy way in rectangular coordinate systems is to use the vector formula
  **P** = *d***(B - A) + A**
where
  **A** is the starting point *(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>)* of the line segment
  **B** is the end point *(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>)*
  *d* is the distance from starting point **A** to the desired collinear point
  **P** is the desired collinear point

Comment: I have compared and tested this solution with the answer from @SenJacob above and this is NOT correct.

Comment: This is the same as Théophile's answer, but it omits to mention that you need to normalize **(B-A)**

Answer (score 1):

I think your method is working. Here is the python code for the test and output of the test is linked below,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, m, c):
    y = m*x + c
    return y

def X(x0,d,m):
    x1 = x0 + (d/np.sqrt(1+m**2))
    x2 = x0 - (d/np.sqrt(1+m**2))
    return np.array([x1, x2])


x = np.arange(1,5,0.5)
m = 1
c = 0.5
plt.plot(x, f(x, m, c), "-")



x0 = 3
d = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])

X = X(x0,d,m)
print(type(X))
plt.plot(X, f(X,m, c), "o")
plt.show()
```

Output of the above code:[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0XJH.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check $x_0 > x_1$ when you try to calculate $x$ (last equation in your calculation) then you determine it will be $(+)$ or $(-)$ in your equation.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This site supports basic TeX syntax, which allows formulas to be nicely typeset as $x_0>x_1$, for example. There is a  [short TeX tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You may want to try using TeX by editing your answer (the link `edit` is under your post). Welcome to Math.SE!

Answer (score 0):

There is an other way to solve this problem.

The function $\rho:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by

$$\rho(t) = (1-t)(x_0,y_0) + t(x_1,y_1)$$

describes the line through the points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ with 
$\rho(0) = (x_0, y_0)$ and $\rho(1)=(x_1,y_1)$. If you let 
$$D = \sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2 + (y_1-y_0)^2},$$ then it is fairly easy to show that

$$|\rho(t) - \rho(s)| = D|t-s|$$

So, if you want to find the points a distance of $d$ from $(x_0,y_0)$, then you need to solve $$d = |\rho(t) - \rho(0)| = D|t-0|$$

You get $ t = \pm \dfrac dD$. Hence the points are

$$\rho\left( \pm \dfrac dD \right) =
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
   \left( 1-\dfrac dD \right)(x_0,y_0) + \dfrac dD (x_1,y_1) \\
   \left( 1+\dfrac dD \right)(x_0,y_0) - \dfrac dD (x_1,y_1)
\end{array} \right.$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, for desired distance *d*, *x* of this point is:

$$
x_1 + d \cdot \cos(\arctan(a)) \iff a = (\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1})
$$

**THIS IS HOW:**

You have given two points:

$$
P = (x_p, y_p)
\\
Q = (x_q, y_q)
$$

and line between them defined with the function *f(x)*:

$$
m = \frac{y_q - y_p}{x_q - x_p}
\\\ \\
f(x) = m(x - x_p) + y_p
$$

or:

$$
a = \frac{y_q-y_p}{x_q-x_p}
\\\ \\
b = \frac{x_{q}y_{p} - x_{p}y_{q}}{x_q-x_p}
\\\ \\
f(x) = ax + b
$$

You're looking for a point *R* between *P* and *Q*.
Note that we can "render" a triangle with the points *P* and *R* and use it to get a width of a side that we have to know. We know one side - it's desired distance, and the angle that equals $\arctan(a)$. Let's see all this stuff in the picture:

[image: Finding point by distance from other ones]

We need to calculate *x'* and then our point *R* is $(x_p+x', f(x_p+x'))$.
Example calculations for desired distance **3**:

- we have two points:

$$
P = (0, 2)
\\
Q = (4, 4)
$$

- and the line between them:

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x + 2
$$

- our distance is **3**:

$$
d = 3
$$

- we're getting an angle:

$$
\alpha = \arctan(\frac{1}{2}) = 0.4637
$$

- now we can get a distance along X-axis:

$$
x' = d \cdot cos(\alpha) = 3 \cdot 0.8944 = 2.6832
$$

so *x* of our point R is:

$$
x_r = x_p + x' = 0 + 2.6832 = 2.6832
$$

and our point is at:

$$
(x_r, f(x_r)) = (2.6832, 3.3416)
$$

---

Example implementation in JavaScript:

```
function findPointByDistance(p1, p2, dist) {
    const [x1,y1] = p1;
    const [x2,y2] = p2;

    const m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
    const f = x => m*(x-x1) + y1;

    const alpha = Math.atan(m);
    const xVector = dist * Math.cos(alpha);
    const foundX = x1 + xVector;

    return 
        foundX,
        f(foundX)
    ].map(v => +v.toFixed(2));
}
```

```
const P = [0,2];
const Q = [4,4];
const d = 3;

findPointByDistance(P, Q, d);
// [ 2.68, 3.34 ]
```