# calculate the coordinate of Point P3 given the following data

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I need to calculate the coordinate of Point P3 given the following data.

```
Distance D from P1 = 3
P1 coord = (1,3)
P2 coord = (10,6)
```

please help me to solve this issue..

i understand I have to use the distance formula between to coordinate.. but my math is very rusty can find the way to calculate the inverse formula.

$$D(P1-P3) = \sqrt{(P2x - P1x)^2 + (P2y - P1y)^2}$$

but... I don't know how to procede.. I need to calculate X,Y of point P3.

can someone show me what the step to take in order to get the coordinate of P3?

Thanks a lot

[image: pic]

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409689/how-do-i-find-a-point-a-given-distance-from-another-point-along-a-line/409721#409721).

Comment: Start with determining vector $\vec{P_1P_2}=(*,*)$. Then find length $P_1P_2=\sqrt{*}$. Vector $\vec{P_1P_3}=\vec{P_1P_2}\frac{P_1P_3}{P_1P_2}=(*,*)$ Then $P_3=(*,*)$.

Comment: Formula in question is not correct. Correct writing is $P_1P_3=\sqrt{(P_{1x}-P_{3x})^2+(P_{1y}-P_{3y})^2}$. If one can use only this formula, one can find $P_1P_2$, then $P_2P_3=P_1P_2-P_1P_3$, then one can solve simultaneous equation for $P_1P_3$ and $P_2P_3$ to find $P_{3x}$ and $P_{3y}$. But this method is weird.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***Use "2-point form"*** to get L, the equation of P1P2.

---> $L: \dfrac {y - 2}{x - 1} = \dfrac {6 - 2}{10 - 1}$

2. Form C, the equation of the circle (centered at P1 with radius = 3).
   ***$C: (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 = 3^3$***
3. ***P3 is located at the intersection of L and C.*** Therefore, solve L and C to get P3. [Will get 2 sets of answers ***from the combined quadratic equation***. Choose the one between P1 and P3.]

Comment: sorry , not so smart on math .. can you show me the math step? thanks  I. don't even know where to start..

Comment: @DamianoMiazzi have added some detail.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, can you please show me with the numbers of the example how to solve it.. I can’t understand  so sorry

Comment: @DamianoMiazzi See another added detail under --->