# Find a point between two geo locations (longitude/latitude)

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I need to find a point between two geolocations **g1** and **g2** (defined by longitude/latitude in radians).
Let's say a positive integer **n**:

- if n = 1, I'm looking for the middle point **m1** between **g1** and **g2**.
- if n = 2, I'm looking for the 'quarter' point **m2** between **g1** and **g2** (middle point between **g1** and **m1**.
- ...

For the middle point, I found the following formula:

$$dLon = lon2 - lon1$$
$$Bx = cos(lat2) \times cos(dLon)$$
$$By = cos(lat2) \times sin(dLon)$$

$$lat3 = atan2(sin(lat1) + sin(lat2), \sqrt{(cos(lat1) + Bx} \times (cos(lat1) + Bx) + By \times By))$$
$$lon3 = lon1 + atan2(By, cos(lat1) + Bx)$$

So I could simply reuse this formula (**n**) times to solve this problem, but maybe there is a way to do it in one operation, while reducing the complexity of the computation?

Comment: You can try adapting the [section formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/section-formula/) to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454530/find-a-point-along-line-on-earth-given-initial-point-and-distance) about finding a point along the great circle between two points on a sphere. In the notation of the answer, I think you are setting $a’ = a/2^n$ where $a$ is the distance between the points (which the answer calculates).