# Find inner stroke value of shape

Tags: geometry

I am writing a application that needs to calculate the inner stroke of a shape.  To understand more of what I mean, imagine we had a shape represented by the black outline of the image bellow.  We than applied a inner stroke effect of 5 to that shape (represented by the yellow).  I would now like to determine the values of **points b0,b1,b2,b3**.  Since this application needs to be fast, I need the solution with the least amount of steps.

[image]

So far this is what I have come up with:

#### Intersection of parallel lines

The main solution I have thought of is getting the parallel lines of **a0,a3** and **a3,a2** with a distance of 5 *(represented by line1 and line2)*.  I would then calculate the intersection point of these two lines and this would determine the point b3.  I would then repeat this step for the remaining points.  This option requires multiple steps;

1. get the perpendicular line of side **a0,a3**. --> **PerpA0,A3**
2. get intersecting point of **a0,a3** and  **PerpA0,A3**  --> **point #2**
3. use line **PerpA0,A3** , **point #2** and the **distance of 5** to calculate **point #3**  [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/175896/592565)
4. find the equation of the line that runs perpendicular to **PerpA0,A3** and passes through **point #3** giving us **line1**
5. repeat the above steps for side **a3,a2** --> **line2**
6. calculate the point of intersection between **line1** and **line2** giving us point **b3**

[image]

I'm no math guru and don't know if this is the best solution for getting these values, If anyone could assist me I would be grateful.  Also this is my first math post.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of a_i? Do you know how to get line equations? Are a_i any in the plan or have some limits? Can you select the coordinate system - such as a_3=(0,0))?

Comment: @Moti all points of a are defined.

Comment: I assume problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the internal angle at a corner be $2A$. Then the corresponding '$b$' point is on the bisector of the angle at a distance $$\frac{5}{\sin A}$$ from the corner.

That should be easy to implement but ask if you are unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will mark it as the correct answer once I test it tomorrow.  Im just a little confused on the "Let the internal angle at a corner be 2A", what is the 2, or is this a misspell.

Comment: Hi. It's easier to call the angle  $2A$ since we need to halve it in the distance formula.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks alot.

Comment: how do i get the equation for the bisector line.  Ive looked around but am just confusing ideas.  Just to make sure im on track, I would then use the distance calculated from point a3 on the bisector line to get my result?

Comment: If $a_3$ is $(x,y)$ then $b_3$ is $(x+5,y+5)$. This can be seen very easily without a formula, but the formula I gave you would work as follows. $A=45$ and so the distance is $d=5/\sin45$ then the coordinates of $b_3$ are $(x+d \cos45,y+d \sin45)$.

Comment: One more thing if you could advise me.  Im getting the internal corner using the "The Law of Cosines".  In this case I have to calculate the distance between points a0,a3,a2 then apply `C = arccos((c² - a² - b² )/(2ab)`.  This is working fine, I was just wondering if you know a faster way. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, from the given coordinates of general points that is probably the best method. However, there may well be quicker methods in special cases - if for example you can easily find right-angled triangles.

Comment: Ok thank, In those cases I would just use sin, cos, and tan right.  SOHCAHTOA - im catching on.  :)

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: So I have been testing out this answer, the distance formula works great for all points, but the (x+dcos45,y+dsin45) does not doo the trick to find the coordinates of other values b0,b1,b3.  Does this (x+dcos45,y+dsin45) only work for corners with 90°. Heres my math https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/tmqdquyf

Comment: Yes, that was only for the 90 angle.

Comment: that only gives me two point then, my primary concern is non 90° angles.  Any guidence on non 90° angles

Comment: Im asuming im going to have to determine the bisector line function and then move d distance on that line

Comment: You need the angle V it makes with the x-axis. Then dcos(V) measures the distance moved in the x-axis etc